# List matching fixed-strings on a per-file basis

Tags: bash, optimization, grep

The following code works, but is quite slow:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.xml; do
  for r in $(cat ../reports.txt); do
    grep -q "$r" $f

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      echo "$r,$f"
    fi
  done
done
```

This could be sped up using:

```
for f in *.xml; do
  grep -lif ../reports.txt $f
done
```

However, this does not display the lines in `reports.txt` that were found to match the file (`$f`).

How would you display the matching lines from `reports.txt` that were found in each file along with the name of the file that had 1 or more matches from `reports.txt`?

For example, if `reports.txt` contains:

```
aardvark
aardwolf
anteater
```

And one of the files (e.g., story.txt) contains:

```
This is a story about an aardvark and an aardwolf.
```

Then I'm trying to produce the following output:

```
story.txt,aardvark
story.txt,aardwolf
```

If it helps, the lines in `reports.txt` aren't regular expressions: they are plain text strings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look this, does it fit your requirement?

```
kent$  head report.txt story.txt
==> report.txt <==
aardvark
aardwolf
anteater

==> story.txt <==
is a story about an aardvark and an aardwolf.

kent$  grep -Hof report.txt story.txt
story.txt:aardvark
story.txt:aardwolf
```

test was done with grep:

```
kent$  grep --version|head -1
grep (GNU grep) 2.14
```

Comment: Irritatingly, on my OS X grep, the output is `story.txt:aardvark<NL>aardwolf`, i.e. the second `story.txt` is missing.

Comment: sorry I don't have a mac to do further test... I paste my grep version in answer.

Comment: That's the argument I was looking for in the man pages. Thanks, Kent.

Comment: Yeah. I was going to post `-Hof` but didn't because my grep didn't produce the desired output.

Comment: btw, If you just want to do a fix-string match, better with -F too. well, just a suggestion.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: Yes, I know that. But, my `grep` doesn't output the filename in front of every line, which makes it harder to parse the output.

Comment: @nneonneo I tested my grep under bash/zsh, both gave the same (as in answer), am I lucky or unlucky... :(

Comment: Lucky. The OS X tools tend to differ in subtle ways from their GNU counterparts :(

Comment: @nneonneo thank you! you know what, I was about to buy a MBP. (I don't have any experience of mac). I went to shop last sunday, with the nice MBP, 5 mins, I didn't find out how to start a terminal... gave up the idea! You gave me just another reason... I love my Linux.(Archlinux) :) well...totally irrelevant to this question. sorry...

Comment: Well, I happen to really like the OS X terminal, and you can install the GNU userland if you want (though there are some gotchas). To get the terminal, go to Applications->Utilities->Terminal.